# CodeCollaborator error:please see the 'svn upgrade' command

Tags: java, svn, subversive

I want to install the tool of CodeCollaborator to manager the code in my development,but there has a install error i cannot handle it.

1. I trusted that the CodeCollaborator client was installed successful.
2. When i click the button of add in the CodeCollaborate Client,and then Add CSM Configration successful.
3. When chose the SCM Cofigration to Add Changes,it always show error  as below:

   **Error initializing changed files**

**Reason:svn:E155036:please see the 'svn upgarade' command**

**svn:E155036:Working copy 'E:\woekplace\chunya' is too old(formate 10,create by Subversion 1.6)**

I think the error is result by the version between **Slik-Subversion-1.7.8-x64** and **Subersion** in my eclipse, but no matter how i to upgrade the version each other, the error has unswerving exist.How to solve this problem?

Comment: Probably means you have changes on the repository for the files you have changed. Have you tried to do `svn update`? Or the equivalent for your tool.

Answer (score 1):

Typing `svn help upgrade` at a Windows command prompt (or `svn --help upgrade` in a Linux terminal) shows this:

```
upgrade: Upgrade the metadata storage format for a working copy.
usage: upgrade [WCPATH...]

Local modifications are preserved.

Valid options:
  -q [--quiet]             : print nothing, or only summary information

Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
  --no-auth-cache          : do not cache authentication tokens
  --non-interactive        : do no interactive prompting
  --trust-server-cert      : accept SSL server certificates from unknown
                             certificate authorities without prompting (but only
                             with '--non-interactive')
  --config-dir ARG         : read user configuration files from directory ARG
  --config-option ARG      : set user configuration option in the format:
                                 FILE:SECTION:OPTION=[VALUE]
                             For example:
                                 servers:global:http-library=serf
```

So it's telling you you need to upgrade **your local working copy's metadata**, not upgrade SVN itself. You do that also from a command prompt or terminal window, using the syntax shown by the `usage` example above.

Comment: Thanks for your help,and the problem has resolved by my friends, thank you onece again.